# rewrite specific query parameter

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Is it possible in nginx to rewrite a url like `mysite.com?t=TVALUE&foo=bar&bar=bazz` to `mysite.com/TVALUE?foo=bar&bar=bazz` ?
All my attempts resulted in infinity redirects or no redirects at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting individual query parameters is possible by using a regular expression on the `$args` or `$request_uri` variable.

For example:

```
location = / {
    if ($args  ~ "^(.*&)?t=([^&]+)(?:&(.*))?$") {
        return 302 /$2?$1$3;
    }
}
```

In the above example, the regular expression consists of:

```
^          beginning of string
(.*&)?     optionally capture prefix up to an ampersand
t=([^&]+)  match and capture the required parameter
(?:&(.*))? optionally capture suffix discarding ampersand
$          end of string
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`, and [this useful resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) on regular expressions.